How are multiple features handled in LTSM Network
I understand how LSTMs function with a single feature, but how do they operate when there are multiple features n? Does the LSTM unit compute a hidden state for each feature separately, resulting in n hidden states for each time step? Or are the features combined at the beginning or the end of the process? If they are combined, what method is used for that combination?

LSTMs (Long Short-Term Memory networks) can handle multiple features effectively, and here's how they typically work with multiple input features:

Input Shape : When you feed data into an LSTM, the input shape is usually three-dimensional: (batch_size, time_steps, num_features) , where num_features corresponds to the number of features you have at each time step. This means that for each time step, all features are provided simultaneously.

Single Hidden State : LSTMs do not compute separate hidden states for each feature. Instead, they maintain a single hidden state (h_t) and a cell state (c_t) that are updated based on all input features at that time step. The hidden state at time t is influenced by the current input features (x_t) , the previous hidden state (h_{t-1}), and the last state cell (c_{t-1}).

Combination of Features : The LSTM unit combines features within its internal computations. The input gate, forget gate, and output gate all use the current input features collectively. Here's how this works:


=> Input Gate : Determines how much of the incoming information should be stored in the cell state.
=> Forget Gate : Decides what information should be discarded from the cell state.
=> Output Gate : Controls what information from the cell state should be output to the hidden state.

Matrix Operations: The operations for combining the features can be summarized mathematically. For a given time step ( t ):

The input to the LSTM is usually represented as ( x_t ) (of shape (num_features,)), and the weights for each gate are learned parameters (matrices) that interact with the features.

The gates are computed as:
[
\begin{align*}
 i_t &= \sigma(W_i \cdot [h_{t-1}, x_t] + b_i) \\
 f_t &= \sigma(W_f \cdot [h_{t-1}, x_t] + b_f) \\
 o_t &= \sigma(W_o \cdot [h_{t-1}, x_t] + b_o) \\
 \tilde{c}_t &= \tanh(W_c \cdot [h_{t-1}, x_t] + b_c)
 \end{align*}

Here, ( W_i, W_f, W_o, W_c ) are weight matrices and ( b_i, b_f, b_o, b_c ) are biases for the input, forget, output gates, and cell state respectively. The concatenation of the previous hidden state and the current input forms a combined vector which captures information from both.




Updating States: The cell state and hidden state are updated based on these calculations:
[
\begin{align*}
   c_t &= f_t \cdot c_{t-1} + i_t \cdot \tilde{c}_t \\
   h_t &= o_t \cdot \tanh(c_t)
   \end{align*}
]


In summary, LSTMs manage multiple features by processing them simultaneously in a combined manner at each time step, maintaining a single hidden and cell state that encapsulates the information from all features over time. This allows them to capture complex patterns and dependencies in sequential data with multiple input features.
References
=> https://medium.com/@anishnama20/understanding-lstm-architecture-pros-and-cons-and-implementation-3e0cca194094
=> https://medium.com/@ottaviocalzone/an-intuitive-explanation-of-lstm-a035eb6ab42c
